# Percents in batch

Tags: batch

The following works in command line but not in a batch file:

```
ffmpeg -i ext_%04d.jpg video.mp4
```

`%0` is parsed as a variable and I can't figure out how to handle it. Is it even possible?

edit : I know how escaping and % work, like in for loops etc, but if I do :
SET "var=ffmpeg -i ext_%%04d.jpg video.mp4", it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. This is commonly called “escaping.” And it is necessary whenever you use special characters within a program. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Answer (score 3):

Use the double percent sign - `%%` - like this :

```
ffmpeg -i ext_%%04d.jpg video.mp4
```

Comment: I already tried playing with double percent and escaping, but it returns an error each time. I'm not a beginner at CMD and this is frustrating.

Comment: the following in batch doesn't work :
SET "Var=ffmpeg -i ext_%%04d.jpg video.mp4"
echoing this displays only one %, but ffmpeg still returns an error

Comment: What is the error and why doesn't ffmpeg like the command?

Comment: "Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'c:\enc\ext2.mp4' [this is the output] (either set update or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found out that "-f image2" was causing the error in the command. Seems like it's not the proper format for converting images to video.